# Function call in v-slot, vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to process some data in v-slot template, but I get the following error:
getNameFromCategory is not defined

What is wrong?

```html
    <template v-slot:items="{ row }" >
    <TableView :rows="results"  >
       <td>{{ getNameFromCategory(row.category) }}</td> 
    </TableView>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {

        components: {
            TableView
        },
            metdods:{
            getNameFromCategory
        },
            props: {
            'results': {
              type: Array,
              required: true
            },

    }
    </script>
```

and then in the TableVue.vue component file:

```html
    <template>
       <template v-if="numRows > 0">
              <tr
                v-for="(row, idx) in rows"
                :key="idx"
              >
                <slot name="items" :row="row"></slot>
              </tr>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'TableView',
      props:{
        rows: {
          type: Array,
          default() {
            return []
          },
          required: true
        },
      }
    }
    </script>
```

It seems that the code passed through the slot template is executed in the component, but I also tried to define the 'getNameFromCategory' function there, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `metdods` instead of `methods`. Also the `getNameFromCategory` is empty i don't know if it is for the sake of the example.
Anyway it should more look like this :

```html
 <template v-slot:items="{ row }" >
    <TableView :rows="results"  >
       <td>{{ getNameFromCategory(row.category) }}</td> 
    </TableView>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {

        components: {
            TableView
        },
            methods:{
            getNameFromCategory(category) {
                return category.name;
            }
        },
            props: {
            'results': {
              type: Array,
              required: true
            },

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Pierre, for discovering this typo! I really appreciate it!